# Is it possible to automatically fix question titles?

Tags: support, questions, editing

This is a request to SE, and while I'm guessing the answer is no, maybe this is something that could be considered if/when we leave beta.

Can question titles be auto-edited when they are submitted? e.g.

```
RPI             -> Raspberry Pi
RasPi           -> Raspberry Pi
!(Raspberry) Pi -> Raspberry Pi
```

Comment: You might want to [read this](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/12/46). We've decided that we don't to include "Raspberry Pi" in the title.

Comment: * unless necessary for grammatical reasons...

Comment: @dunsmoreb SE has no strict policy on the matter, though [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10648/150214) is as close as you can get. On SO, Languages in titles: OK as long as it makes sense.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Well exactly, in which case I thought we had decided to [use the correct, full name](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/43/160).

Comment: @TomMedley We decided to use the full name in questions, but to edit it out in titles.

Comment: @dunsmoreb Yes, I understand that, but sometimes it's impossible to avoid. '[Can the Pi be potted in epoxy?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/119/160)'.

Comment: @TomMedley Does it really matter?

Comment: @dunsmoreb That's up to the community!

Answer (score 4):

This seems to have come up time and time again - but seriously, does it really matter? Are we not spending time over the wrong things here? Should our effort not be focused on more important things such as those 7 essential meta questions floating around, attracting more members to the site, posting good, useful questions and answers and so on?

As long as it's clear (which "Raspberry Pi", "Pi", "RPi" all are) I don't see the need to enforce a particular preference - and let's face it, that's all it is. Yes, I think blatantly redundant uses of "Pi" (in whatever form) should probably be removed, but let's not start automatically editing titles just to impose an arbitrary preference. There's much more important stuff to focus on.